# Problem mat-form-field outline background-color on hover

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-form-field

I have a CSS problem when I pass my mouse over a `mat-form-field`.

To be able to use a colored mat-card, I added some CSS class in `style.scss` to change the `background-color` of the `mat-form-field`.

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start { background-color: white!important; }
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-gap { background-color: white!important; }
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end { background-color: white!important; }
mat-form-field mat-label { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); }
```

It works fine, but when I hover my mouse over a `mat-form-field`,
the background turns red for a fraction of a second.
Unfortunately I can't find the CSS class allowing me to remove this transparency.

**StackBlitz:** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-form-field-outline-background-over)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by this css:

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .6s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
```

On hover it transitions the opacity to `0`, causing the effect you show. You could fix this by overriding the transition on the hover.

---

For future reference you can find thid by using the dev inspector in your browser:

[image]

I invoked the hover effect on the element and inspected the styles that were added

Comment: I changed the opacity to 1 and it works. And for the hover, the class does not appear in my project, even in :hover, it's a mystery. thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: How to apply it in the class in html with that css format? Sorry I'm not a frontend guy...

Answer (score 2):

you can change the color of hover by this. Here you can give any color you want.
just add this css in your code.

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  color: rgba($grey, 0.75) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With bit less code and I think `ViewEncapsulation.None` is the important:

CSS:

```
.mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: none !important;
}
```

TS:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-appearance-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-appearance-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-appearance-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

[`Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-form-field-outline-background-over-dcwkhk)