# iOS Safari (Mobile) and Angular Material UI: unwanted blinky text when focusing on the input field

Tags: safari, angular-material, mobile-safari, placeholder

When switching focus between text fields, the iOS Safari 13 gives an unwanted disappearance of text animation.

- This happens on iPhone and iPhone simulator
- Desktop Safari seems to be good
- iOS 13
- Input field has a text placeholder
- Angular Material UI `<mat-form-field>` is used

The problem is demonstrated in the GIF animation below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a transition animation on `mat-form-field-outline` that plays badly on iPhone. I guess this is because the keyboard pops up and that somehow makes the transition play differently than on other web browsers.

The solution is to disable the transition animation:

```
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline {
    transition: none !important;
  }
```

See also: [Problem mat-form-field outline background-color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354992/problem-mat-form-field-outline-background-color-on-hover)